# Get width and height of plotly figure

Tags: python, plotly, plotly-python

e.g. if I write

```py
import plotly.express as px

df = px.data.tips()
fig = px.scatter(df, x="total_bill", y="tip", facet_col="sex")
```

then how can I get the width and height of `fig`?

If I do

```
fig.layout.width
```

then I get `None`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

That is the correct way to get the `width`.

`fig.layout.width` is `None` because the width has not been set yet.

If you set it explicitly you can retrieve it

```
fig = px.scatter(df, x="total_bill", y="tip", facet_col="sex", width=200)
>>> fig.layout.width
200
```

[If not set explicitly the width is initialised when executing the `show` method based on defaults defined by `plotly.js`](https://plotly.com/python-api-reference/generated/plotly.graph_objects.Figure.html#plotly.graph_objects.Figure.show).

> show(*args, **kwargs)
> Show a figure using either the default renderer(s) or the renderer(s) specified by the renderer argument
>
> Parameters
> ...
> width (int or float) – An integer or float that determines the number of pixels wide the plot is. The default is set in plotly.js.
> ...

If we look at the `plotly.js` documentation we see the [default `width` is `700`](https://plotly.com/javascript/reference/layout/#layout-width) and the [default `height` is `450`](https://plotly.com/javascript/reference/layout/#layout-height).

If you set `fig.layout.autosize = False` you can see that these defaults are correct. Otherwise the `width` and `height` are re-initialised on each relayout.

> autosize: Determines whether or not a layout width or height that has been left undefined by the user is initialized on each relayout. Note that, regardless of this attribute, an undefined layout width or height is always initialized on the first call to plot.

https://plotly.com/javascript/reference/layout/#layout-autosize